# What is the alternative of switchable controller in typo3

Tags: typo3

What if two different methods of an extension need to be called in two different places?

Example:
What if I want to use the method of one controller of the same extension on the home page and the method of another controller on another page?

Answer (score 4):

Create two different plugins.

Example: Instead of flexform

```
<switchableControllerActions>
   <TCEforms>
      <label>switchable controller actions</label>
      <config>
         <renderType>selectSingle</renderType>
         <items>
            <numIndex index="1">
               <numIndex index="0">List</numIndex>
               <numIndex index="1">Product->list</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
            <numIndex index="2">
               <numIndex index="0">Show</numIndex>
               <numIndex index="1">Product->show</numIndex>
            </numIndex>
         </items>
      </config>
   </TCEforms>
</switchableControllerActions>
```

Create two plugins.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'extension',
    'list',
    [
        'Product' => 'list'
    ]
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'extension',
    'show',
    [
        'Product' => 'show'
    ]
);
```

More details see https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html

Comment: Note that in TYPO3 v11 you need the  fully-qualified controller class name.